Sheldrake's Fields as Formal Causes
Why do we not consider fields as formal causes, especially in light of Rupert Sheldrake's analysis of morphogenetic fields? How does Sheldrake's hypothesis of formative causation challenge our understanding of biological organization and development?
Sheldrake, a British process biologist, introduced the theory of morphic fields through his Hypothesis of Formative Causation in the early 1980s. These fields consist of patterns that govern the development of forms, structures, and arrangements. Sheldrake proposes that there is a field within and around a morphic unit (such as a cell, organ, or organism) that organizes its characteristic structure and pattern of activity. Here are some key points related to morphic fields:
1. Holistic Organization:
Sheldrake suggests that morphogenetic fields are as real as gravitational, electromagnetic, and quantum matter fields.
Every cell, organ, and organism has its own field, forming a nested hierarchy of fields that shape and organize all life forms.
These fields play a crucial role in determining the overall organization and development of living systems.
2. Beyond Genes:
While genes and gene products are essential for development, they alone cannot explain the complexity of biological organization.
Morphogenesis (the process of form development) depends not only on genes but also on organizing fields.
Identifiable genes switch on and regulate protein synthesis, but they do not fully account for the overall organization of an organism.
3. Memory and Habit:
Sheldrake’s hypothesis challenges the notion that biological laws are fixed and unchanging.
He proposes that memory is inherent in nature, and most so-called “laws” are more like habits.
Morphic fields carry the memory of past forms and behaviors, influencing the development of new ones.
4. Patterns and Repetition:
Morphic fields are set up by the repetition of similar acts and/or thoughts.
Organisms inherit these fields, which guide their development.
The theory of morphic resonance suggests that similar forms resonate with each other across space and time, reinforcing specific patterns.
5.    Holons and Morphic Units:
oHolons (entities that are both whole and part) emerge from the interplay of morphic fields.
Morphic units (such as cells) participate in this dynamic process, influenced by their surrounding fields.
In summary, Sheldrake’s theory challenges reductionist views by emphasizing the importance of holistic organization and morphic fields in shaping living systems. These fields, rather than genes alone, contribute to the intricate dance of form and function in the natural world.

Re. “How does Sheldrake's hypothesis of formative causation challenge our understanding of biological organization and development?” It might require a new form of consciousness.

"Questions" that push a personal philosophy are not appropriate for this forum.

Because they are analogs of mean fields in physics, and were introduced as such by Driesch 100 years before Sheldrake, see Goodwin. While useful as averaged high level descriptions of molecular processes, they do not involve top down causation and teleology that Sheldrake ascribes to them. His further explorations in this area, "morphic resonance", "telephone telepathy" and "telepathic dogs", are just pseudo-science, see Woolfe.

I'm not a part of the high clergy of science, so I don't police the gates of nominalism. Sheldrake--the heretic--doesn't have his Whitehead right, but that doesn't mean he is wrong.

I don't see a question, but I agree with Sheldrake; teleology is a foundational principle of reality, no matter how you look at it. Also a question for scepticals: How different do you think are Sheldrake's propositions (about morphogenetic fields), from the recent (and older ones too) interpretations of QM regarding the orbits of particles and the particles themselves?

@Conifold -- Woolfe's blog post contains one falsehood after another.  He says Sheldrake never published in journals-- false, see: https://www.sheldrake.org/research/all-scientific-papers. He claims S's work was not peer reviewed.  The first two journals I checked ARE peer reviewed.  He claims one cannot review S's work, but the Kane paper in question is readily accessed.  He claim's  Wiseman's test refutes S's results, but W used a bogus scoring metric of "first time on window ledge", for a dog that was hyperactive.  The behavior change was to REMAIN on the ledge.

Wiseman's bogus scoring metric, appears deliberately chosen to mask a real phenomenon, I consider it data fraud by Wiseman.  Woolfe than claims that a 10% effect deviation from the mean is not significant in a 10,000 item test!!!!! That is lying about statistics! He also offers no other alternative, just "It could be something other than telepathy".  Of course!  But with no alternatives, science works with the predictive model. He also implies that the effect is not real, because Wiseman did not show it.  But attention by the experimenter is part of the test, and under Wiseman's control.

Denier failure under such conditions is expected under the attention-psi hypothesis, is seen in many other psi tests, and was verified in Wiseman's joint tests with Schlitz.  https://marilynschlitz.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Wiseman-and-Schlitz-1999.pdf  Woolfe's "case" is just a series of falsehoods. There is pseudo-science at work here, but it is by Woolfe and Wiseman, not Sheldrake!

I see three parts to your question, and will try to answer 1) about causes, 2) about biological organization and 3) about Sheldrakes ideas specifically.  With an addendum 4) on why Sheldrake and morphic resonance do not get the positive attention they deserve.
1) Causation
Aristotle's four types of cause have a very unclear causal interaction with each other.  Subsequent thinking has basically collapsed to one kind of cause, not 4. What that 1 kind looks like, though, has changed significantly over time.
Descartes articulated the simplified causal system, where one thing just leads to a second. For matter, it was mechanical contact.  For thoughts, it was reasoning.
Mechanical contact was refuted by: wind, liquids, and superposition (fluid dynamics), then Newton's gravity.  Hume pointed out that causation was at that point equivalent to correlation.
Reasoning lasted a bit longer than mechanical contact contact did, but Freud and his studies of the unconscious thoroughly refuted reasoning as the primary cause of thoughts.
Causation today has adopted Popper's addition to Hume.  Find correlations, develop a conjecture as to what might be happening behind the scenes, and if the conjecture passes refusion tests, then one has found a cause!
Sheldrake's Morphic Fields are a credible potential cause under current science protocol, but they need to make a lot of useful, then tested, predictions.
2) Biological Organization needing non-reductive processes as explanation
That biology, and psychology, and sociology, etcetera, may need to invoke something other than reductionism to explain them is now the dominant view in science and philosophy.  See section 5 of SEP on Scientific Reductionism: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-reduction/
What that alternative is, is still being hashed out.  The most common alternative being considered is emergence, which in its strong form breaks causal closure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergentism.  The second most common response is just to accept pluralism as intrinsic to science and knowledge, and leave the "how" to later consideration.
Sheldrake is among the thinkers who consider emergence alone to be insufficient to explain the complexity of life.  He has loads of fellow travelers in this belief.  A few examples:  Paul Davies and Stuart Kauffman https://global.oup.com/academic/product/at-home-in-the-universe-9780195111309?cc=us&lang=en& and Gregg Henriques http://www.gregghenriques.com/overview-of-the-system.html all postulate some kind of logic or force in the universe that increases complexity, or information.
Thomas Nagel considers emergence plus a complexity principle to be too weak to explain consciousness and reasoning, and adds in the idea the universe has a GOAL to achieve reasoning.  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1HQMF6OJKRDCC?ref=pf_ov_at_pdctrvw_srp Sheldrake joins Nagle in assuming teleology is the driver here.
Iain McGilchrist argues that we need not jstu emergence, but holism as well in our worldview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matter_with_Things
Each of these will require a theory of interaction in which their postulated solution is causal on matter in the world.  Each of these ideas breaks the causal closure of reductionism.
3) Sheldrake's thinking
Unlike most of the other thinkers I listed, Sheldrake has actually fleshed his general idea out into a specific, testable conjecture.  This is how science advances, when general ideas are detailed, and therefore become testable.  Sheldrake deserves nothing but praise for this.
I have skimmed through Sheldrake's papers, and only fund three that looked to be actual tests of the morphic resonance thesis, as most of the rest were tests of telepathy f various kinds.  Telepathy could be achieved by multiple non-physicalist methodologies, so morphic resonance is not explicitly supported by success of telepathy.  The most explicit was a speculative discussion of cattle and fake cattle guards, in which Sheldrake speculated that even newly born herds avoided the fake guards because other (far distant) cattle had been injured by real ones.  However, Sheldrake, in that speculation, noted that with the strong temptation of food, a brave cow will try to cross the fake guard, and then the others will too, thereafter.  I believe that under morphic resonance, this understanding of the difference between fake and real cattle guards should then have transferred to all cattle worldwide, making this an instance of a falsification of morphic resonance!
I did not yet find the 1988 paper he references on how rats learn faster a maze that other rats have learned.
I am personally highly suspicious of morphic resonance, as humans do not learn other languages spontaneously, and education in general is a very time consuming and difficult process for us, and both seem like they would be otherwise if morphic resonance were true.
But if Sheldrake has a false conjecture -- GOOD FOR HIM!  The vast majority of conjectures in the sciences are false!
4) Why is there so much hostility to Sheldrake?
Sheldrake is one of the leading parapsychology researchers.  The Organized Skeptics movement has from its founding engaged in smears and character assassinations of parapsychology and parapsychologists, and Sheldrake has been subjected to this smear campaign for his entire career.  That campaign extends to any ideas or work outside of the parapsychology research of parapsychologists, and so has been extended to morphic resonance as well.  For an example of the smear campaign in operation, see this blog, which I have now posted a rebuttal comment on. https://www.samwoolfe.com/2013/07/the-problem-with-rupert-sheldrake.html#comment-3715
